# Excel linking two to three column

Tags: microsoft-excel

i have a table of productid, product name and price. In Excel Productid i want to give as drop down & on selection of particular id the respective name and price should appear in next column automatically.

Kindly suggest me how to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure :)

Firstly, create a drop list using *data validation*, using the list of ProductIDs as your validation criterion.

In excel 2010 / 2013 this is under the DATA tab in the ribbon.

Secondly, use Vlookup function to both find your price and product name

```
=VLOOKUP("PRODUCTID","PRODUCTID_NAME_PRICE_LIST","COLUMN_WITH_NAME",FALSE)

=VLOOKUP("PRODUCTID","PRODUCTID_NAME_PRICE_LIST","COLUMN_WITH_PRICE",FALSE)
```

[image: Example]

Alternatively, should you wish to have the name and price appear in the same column, then:

```
 =VLOOKUP("PRODUCTID","PRODUCTID_NAME_PRICE_LIST","COLUMN_WITH_NAME",FALSE)&" "&VLOOKUP("PRODUCTID","PRODUCTID_NAME_PRICE_LIST","COLUMN_WITH_PRICE",FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks alot....  can i get a sample xl for the same what u have shown here, i am facing some problem in Vlookup formula

Comment: Sure, drop me a mail thekaizenbuddha @ gmail . com (no spaces) and I will revert with the requisite spreadsheet